# What reason is there to give a JS function a name if you can't use it?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet:

```
let myFunc = function foo() {
   console.log('whatever');
}

myFunc(); // 'whatever'
foo();    // ReferenceError
```

What reason is there to give this function a name if you can't use it?

Comment: It's very useful when you are debugging it since the stacktrace will list the function name instead of "anonymous".

Answer (score 0):

A named function is to call itself with this given name. The name can not changed later.

For example this function is calling itself only two times.

```js
let myFunc = function foo() {
   console.log('whatever');
   foo.count = (foo.count || 0) + 1;
   if (foo.count < 3) foo();
}

myFunc();
```